# How to dynamically change the button color in android?

Tags: java, android, button, handler

I want to change the button color dynamically.

After writing, testing and researching, I found that the display thread should be different then the code, so I used a handler.

I am trying to change the color of a button from default to black for some time and then getting it back to default color,
but it is not happening, it just shows a default button.

Following is my code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Handler ;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button b1;
    Random r = new Random();
    int random_selection;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);



 main();

}
public void main() {
    // Thread t1 = new Thread(new MainActivity());
    // this wi run() function

    Handler handler1 = new Handler();



        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                int count = 0;
                try {
                    System.out.println("inside run");
                    for (i=0;i<4 ;i++ )

                      //  android.widget.Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), count,android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                        int x = randomgen();
                          //  android.widget.Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), x,android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (x == 1) {
                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                }
                            }, 10000);


                        } else if (x == 2) {
                            b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    b2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                }
                            }, 2000);


                        } else if (x == 3) {
                            b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    b3.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                }
                            }, 2000);


                        } else if (x == 4) {
                            b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    b4.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                                }
                            }, 2000);


                        }


                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("inside catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, 1000 );


}

public int randomgen() {
    random_selection = r.nextInt(4) + 1;
    return random_selection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being is your `b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);`

is outside of the delayed handler,

Change your function `main` to this:

```
public void main() {

    int count = 0;
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();

    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        Handler handler2 = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("inside run");


                //     android.widget.Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), x,android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                    }
                }, 2000);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("inside catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: but if i use four buttons and select them randomly and then use same code like if(x=1) then above code elseif x=2 then above code for b2 ....,but more then on turns black for 2s,and then nothing happens

Comment: @G.ONE Post your code showing that and I can take a look at it

Comment: I have added the code ,what i want is only one button should color at a time ,but multiple buttons are getting black at same time

Comment: generating random number between 1 to 4

Comment: @G.ONE what's happening is your `randomgen` can output a number that was already used. if you `System.out.println("random number:: " + x);` you will see it can be the same. Do you want them to not be?

Comment: no they can be same ,randomgen will select any one, it should turn color ,then again in next loop cycle any one will be selected ,so it can be previous one .but here what happening is like loop is running without waiting for delay hence ,x is selected 4 times virtually at the same time and looks like multiple buttons  turn black at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Thread instead:

```
b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { System.sleep(2000) } catch(Exception e) {}
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: thanks its working but if i use four buttons and select them randomly and then use same code like if(x=1) then above code elseif x=2 then above code for b2 ....,but more then on turns black for 2s,and then nothing happens

Comment: Check your code, may be you are placing something in the wrong way. I suggest you to put my code inside a method with the following parameters changeButton(Button b1) {// Above code}